# Google Geolocation JS API Giving Nonsense Lat/Long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the following code, with a valid API key, to obtain latitude and longitude from the Google Geocoder JS API:

```
<script async defer type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[key]">
</script>
<script>
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            console.log (results[0]);
            // results[0].geometry.location.lat
            // results[0].geometry.location.lng
        }
        else console.log(status, results);
    });
</script>
```

The query to the Google server works fine, and brings back results. The problem is that no matter what address I enter, `location.lat` comes back as `_.E/this.lat()` and `location.lng` comes back as `_.E/this.lng()`. The viewport coordinates are fine, but the actual latitude and longitude results are nonsense to me. The same thing happens if I put the code into a function and pass it as a callback.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? Is there something I'm missing? I can't find anything anywhere about this problem when I search, and this is my first time using the API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`results[0].geometry.location` is a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng). It doesn't have `.lat`/`.lng` properties, they are functions, you need to call them:

```
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results[0]);
      var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else console.log(status, results);
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vffk18jc/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results[0]);
      var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
      var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
      var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      iw.setContent("lat:" + lat + "<br>lng:" + lng);
      iw.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
      iw.open(map);
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    } else console.log(status, results);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```